# How to replace values in a tag for a batch of xml files using python

Tags: python, xml, list

I have around 900 xml files in the format given below:

```
<annotation>
<folder>EMap</folder>
<filename>EricMap-lm005.jpg</filename>
<path>C:\Ashwij\EMap\EricMap-lm005.jpg</path>
<object>
    <name>GreenHose</name>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>376</xmin>
    </bndbox>
</object>
</annotation>
```

The numbers in `<bndbox>` are different for different xml files.
I have a list of values, say `lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, ......]`
I am trying to write a python code to replace the values in `<bndbox>` with values in the list.

So far I have tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('EricMap-lm005.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
 
bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

for tag in bs_data.find_all('object', {'bndbox'}):
    tag['xmin'] = "100"
   
print(bs_data.prettify())
```

But this is only for one xml file and one value. Is there a way to parse a list through the `<xmin>` tag for different xml files?

Comment: Do you have a filename pattern for your XML files? Are they all in the same directory? Do you intend to rewrite the files?

Comment: All the xml files start with the name "EricMap". And yes, all the xml files are present in the same directory. I intend to rewrite all the files.

Comment: Next question. How do you associate the values in your list with the various files?

Comment: The first element of the list must replace the value in the xmin tag of the first xml file. The second list element with the xmin tag of second xml file, and so on.

Comment: Next question. What if there are more files than there are items in the list?

Comment: There are exactly samenumber of elements in the list as the number of xml files. Example: lis = [1,2,3,4,5] . Number of xml files = 5